just installed Installed Android Studio successfully but cat run due to buid failures
The build failures are due to errors such asenter image description here
enter image description here
How can I remove this aar dependency compatibility issues error.
I have uninstalled android studio and reinstalled, I expected the errors not to show anymore. Do I need to reinstall both AS and java?

Are you using one of the built-in project templates?

@John Obure, can you please add your error in the question, the error you are getting during building, It will be helpful for us to give you the right answer,
